# Django image dosen't show when searching?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have an inventory app with products and its name, photo.

I  query the records in HTML page and all works fine and the images showing.

when i try to search the result come without the photo.

View:

```
def inventory_search_view(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    product_search = Inventory.objects.filter(name__icontains = query).values()
    print(product_search)
    context = {'object_list': product_search}
    return render(request, 'inventory_search.html', context = context)
```

HTML:

```
    {%for object in object_list %}
    <div class="product-image">
        
        <img src="{{object.image}}" alt="{{object.name}}" />
        
    
    <div class="info">
        <h2> Description</h2>
        <ul>
            {{object.description}} 
            
            
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
{%endfor%}
```

search form:

```
    <form action="search/">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">

    </form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if your remove `.values()`?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: Context contains `object_list` , but `object` is used. Is there a loop in the HTML outside of what you provided?

Comment: es there is a loop but stack overflow doesn't allow to put all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using .values()? Why not pass the queryset to the page?
In the page you should also do object.image.url I believe.

```
def inventory_search_view(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    product_search = Inventory.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
    print(product_search)
    context = {'object_list': product_search}
    return render(request, 'inventory_search.html', context=context)
```

And in your template:

```
{%for object in object_list %}
    <div class="product-image">
        
        <img src="{{object.image.url}}" alt="{{object.name}}" />
        
    
        <div class="info">
            <h2> Description</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>{{object.description}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
{% comment %} </div> This shouldn't be here, or you're missing some code in your question {% endcomment %} 
{% endfor %}
```